# Hebrew as Gibberish on the server side

Tags: iphone, json, networking, endianness, hebrew

I have an iPhone simulator app as client and WCF-REST, json encoded service running on IIS 7.0 server.
I'm trying to send some hebrew characters to the service as parameter and the server return error code 400 - Bad Request.
When I'm sending an English string the server processes the string as it should.

The code used for the string encoding looks like this:

Note that "parameters" is the parameters that about to be sent to the server, ordered as parameter_name => parameter_value.

```
//RPC JSON
NSString* reqString = [parameters JSONRepresentation];
//Request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSData* requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[reqString UTF8String] length:[reqString length]];
//prepare http body
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

The request and response I'm getting in the server side (got this by using ethereal):

Request:

```
POST /SmsliMobileService.svc/SetContactGroups HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.10.22:8081
User-Agent: Beeper_3/1.0 CFNetwork/485.12.7 Darwin/10.7.0
Content-Length: 89
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response:

```
{"ApplicationID":"98534bb6-82ef-4937-83e7-10f65780bf36","contact_id":43,"groups":"עבו×HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 1647
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2011 07:46:09 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"             "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-    left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-    bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }     A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active {     color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-    color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-    size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-    left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding:     5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-    wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse;     border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid;     border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td {     border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for     more details.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a server-side problem to me. That error could be caused by any exception firing in your server program. Either enable the debug mode on the server so you can see the full exception in the response, or look a the logs, to see what the error is.

Comment: I've posted the raw request and response. Isn't it the best debugging we can get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error on the posted code.

```
NSData* requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[reqString UTF8String] length:[reqString length]];
```

This line (was originally in the question's code) generated the error - instead of taking the length of the bytes array returned from: "[reqString UTF8String]", a wrong length had been given - the length of the nsstring...

The fixed code:

```
const char *utf8String = [reqString UTF8String];    // no need to free me - autoreleased  object returned.
NSInteger l = strlen(utf8String);
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:utf8String length:l];
```